# A story about an increasingly advanced civilisation that suddenly collapses

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story that I read long ago - probably in the 90es, and probably a short story. What I remember is that it was about humanity developing more and more advanced computing technology and storing all knowledge in smaller and smaller technology, which none the less grew to cover Earth and later the whole Solar system. And then one day, there was a serious problem, and they realised they didn't know how to find the information to fix it anymore. What would be the title and author?

Comment: seen it on tvtropes, I'll try to find it.

Comment: Another old story involving data compression is James Blish's classic *Beep* https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/204354/116908

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This sounds very much like "[MS Fnd in a Lbry](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93729) " by Hal Draper, a short story first publised in 1961 in the Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction.

A summary on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Fnd_in_a_Lbry) describes the plot as:

> The title of the short story comes from the fact that all redundancy -
> and vowels - had been removed from our language in order for the
> information volume to shrink. Finally the sum of all human knowledge
> was compressed by means of subatomic processes and stored away in a
> drawer-sized box. However the access to that information required
> complicated indices, bibliographies etc., which soon outgrew the size
> of all knowledge.
>
> ...
>
> The use of indices grew exponentially, comprising a pseudo-city,
> pseudo-planet and eventually a pseudo-galaxy devoted to information
> storage. At this point, a case of circular reference was encountered,
> and the civilization needed to refer to the first drawer-sized box to
> find the error. However, this drawer had been lost in the
> pseudo-galaxy, and soon the civilization fell apart while trying to
> locate the first drawer.

Although he is best known as being a socialist activist and writing "The ABC of Marxism", Draper worked for a period as the microfilm acquisitions librarian at the University of California, which may have inspired this short story - his only work of science fiction.

Comment: We posted the same answer basically simo; I'm deleting mine. Cheers!

Comment: @OrganicMarble you are a gentleman sir. But if we ever jinx each other again, I will be the one to delete my answer

Comment: Unaccepted answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55962/story-about-a-library-built-in-the-ocean/55964#55964) and  [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70659/story-about-a-dystopian-future-involving-data-planets/70664#70664). Accepted [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255715/1950s-short-story-where-the-universe-is-running-out-of-space-to-store-data/255717#255717).

Comment: Note that this scenario is unlikely. We already have effective compression methods in which the compressed data plus the compressor are together smaller than the raw data. A civilization would have to be extremely short sighted to fail in the way outlined here.

Comment: @Mack Agreed, but data compression was still very much in its infancy when this story was published. Some lossless compression schemes had been developed, eg Huffman, but the LZ family were almost 2 decades in the future. Sci-fi computers from that era can be rather quaint. Eg, in Heinlein's *Starman Jones* (from 1953) data input & output was in binary, and one of the protagonist's skills is that he's memorized a binary logarithm table. :)

Comment: Wow! I am reading the story and I love its tongue in cheeck humour: "This building, 25 miles square and two miles high, was buried in one of the oceans to save land surface for parking space"; "One of the asteroids was converted into an annex, called the Asteroidal Storage Station. In thirteen yukals, all the ASS's were filled in the original solar system."